# How to configure Angular $http to send requests to different host?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, requirejs

I have an Angular web app deployed onto Heroku that pulls static files from S3. I have RequireJS enabled to allow angular to lazily load controllers and templates. The problem is that when the app is loaded, the window.location variable is set to `myapp.heroku.com`, and so all angular requests to load the templates try to do something like this `myapp.heroku.com/path/to/my/template.html` when I want them to do this `mybucket.s3.amazon.com/path/to/my/template.html`. I had to do a little hack to get RequireJS to load the files from S3 instead of Heroku, but I can't seem to figure out how to modify Angular's $http service so that all requests go to S3. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Angular to load the templates from S3 instead of the current host! First, some here's tech I'm using:

- RequireJS for making my application modular
- Angular
- Angular UI Router for state routing in the application
- Angular AMD to help reconcile Angular with RequireJS

The solution entails a creating a RequireJS module called it `config.js` that grabs the configured baseURL straight from RequireJS like so:

```
define([], function(){
    var baseUrl = require.s.contexts._.config.baseUrl;
    var host = baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.indexOf('/', baseUrl.indexOf('://') + 3)) + "/";
    return {
        baseUrl :  baseUrl,
        hostUrl : host
    }
 });
```

This is a bit hacky, as I'm accessing a not very public RequireJS API. Later versions of RequireJS might change the way you access the config. I export both the baseURL and the hostURL since they both could be useful.

Now, in my module that actually defines all the states and template routes, I just import this module and prepend the hostUrl to the templateUrl given to Angular UI Router like so:

```
define(['angularAMD', 'config'], function(angularAMD, config){
'use strict';
var host = config.hostUrl;
var routes = {};
routes.authenticated = {};
routes.unauthenticated = {};
routes.unauthenticated.splash = angularAMD.route({
    name: 'splash',
    url: '/splash',
    templateUrl : host +'static/webpages/views/splash.html', 
    controller: 'splashController',
    controllerUrl : 'controllers/splash'
});
return routes;
```

});

We're still not done yet. We also have to whitelist the S3 domain in the $sceProvider like so:

```
var app = angular.module('webapp', ['ui.router', 'LocalStorageModule']);
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider){
        $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        // Allow same origin resource loads.
        'self',
        'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/**',
        'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/**'
     ]);
});
```

The root cause of my error came from the fact that RequireJS and AngularAMD can be used in tandem to load Javascript files, but they will not load HTML files for you. Angular and Angular UI Router are still going to be responsible for loading the template.